# Tabledit Ajax fail => parsererror : SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i want to use the tableedit JQuery Plugin. This is a code example. The edit of the table is working. But the delete doesnt work. I get the error:
Tabledit Ajax fail => parsererror : SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON

I dont understand why. I have read some Posts here, but I have the Problem yet.

Here is my code:

```html
<?php
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "testing");
$query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_user ORDER BY id DESC";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
?>
<html>  
    <head>  
        <title>Live Table Data Edit Delete using Tabledit Plugin in PHP</title>  
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />  
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>            
        <script src="jquery.tabledit.min.js"></script>
    </head>  
    <body>  
        <div class="container">  
        <br />  
        <br />  
        <br />  
        <div class="table-responsive">  
            <h3 align="center">Live Table Data Edit Delete using Tabledit Plugin in PHP</h3><br />  
            <table id="editable_table" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
     <?php
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
     {
      echo '
                <tr>
                    <td>'.$row["id"].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row["firstname"].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row["lastname"].'</td>
                </tr>
      ';
     }
     ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>  
        </div>  
    </body>  
</html>  
<script>  
$(document).ready(function(){  
     $('#editable_table').Tabledit({
      url:'action.php',
      columns:{
       identifier:[0, "id"],
       editable:[[1, 'firstname'], [2, 'lastname']]
      },
      restoreButton:false,
      onSuccess:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
      {
       if(data.action == 'delete')
       {
        $('#'+data.id).remove();
       }
      }
     });
});
 </script>
```

```
<?php  
//action.php
$connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'testing');

$input = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST);

$firstname = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $input["firstname"]);
$lastname = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $input["lastname"]);

if($input["action"] === 'edit'){
    $query = "
    UPDATE tbl_user 
    SET firstname = '".$firstname."', 
         lastname = '".$lastname."' 
    WHERE id = '".$input["id"]."'
    ";

    mysqli_query($connect, $query);    
}

if($input["action"] === 'delete'){
    $query = "
    DELETE FROM tbl_user 
    WHERE id = '".$input["id"]."'
    ";
    mysqli_query($connect, $query);   
}
header('Content-type: application/json');
print_r(json_encode($input));
?>
```

Comment: But why ? I say Json

Comment: [`print_r`](http://fi2.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) seems not to be a suitable PHP function to send JSON ... Try with `echo json_encode($input);`

Comment: Look at the response from the server..... debug it

Comment: I used echo before it hasnt worked

Comment: Then back to the ajax code. You've to check, what you're actually getting as the response, then fix the problem at the server-side. For debugging you might need to configure Tabledit, or use a regular jQuery.ajax call to avoid the internal error occuring in Tabledit.

Comment: Thank you Teemu i know what is the error now. When I click delete I got an error on the server side i see because I have an undefined index for lastname and firstname. because these indexes doesnt exist when deleting. So I solve the problem with a condition if the indexes are setted. I hope could explain !